# Globally Set Time Zone in Team Foundation Server 2017

Tags: timezone, tfs-workitem, tfs-2017

I have many users in different locales so they have different time zones. I have a field in one of my work items that contain a date. Whenever it is set, it is supposed to default to 12:00:00 PM in the anytime zone, but instead, it gets set to the user's locale and gets translated to the work item viewer's locale.

E.G. :

> User 1 from (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) creates a work item
> with a date field 8/30/2022 12:00 AM
>
> User 2 from (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) views the same work
> item, but the date field is now 8/29/2022 9:00 PM

This discrepancy has caused confusion. I want it so when displayed to the viewer, the field is 12:00 AM as opposed to a translated value from the server's time zone.

Right now the workaround is to ask all users to set everyone's locale to the same. As a Team Foundation Server administrator, is there a settings option to set all users' locale to the same? I've searched for answers online, but they all point to Azure DevOps Server fixes.

A secondary workaround I am considering is if there is a way to modify the work item type and force the field to be a certain timezone.